# How to reduce CPU usage in network bandwidth script

Tags: c#, networking, interface, system, cpu

I'm writing this class to monitor the bandwidth passing through all of the network interfaces. Although this whole thing works wonderfully, I want to try and reduce the CPU usage during the query. The reason is because I run this every couple of seconds and it adds about 7-8% more CPU usage to the process every time. Is there any way I can reduce the amount of CPU cycles?

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
        String[] instancename = category.GetInstanceNames();

        foreach (string name in instancename)
        {
            String networkCard = name;

            const int numberOfIterations = 10;

            PerformanceCounter bandwidthCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Current Bandwidth", networkCard);

            float bandwidth = bandwidthCounter.NextValue();

            PerformanceCounter dataSentCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", networkCard);

            PerformanceCounter dataReceivedCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", networkCard);

            float sendSum = 0;
            float receiveSum = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfIterations; index++)
            {
                sendSum += dataSentCounter.NextValue();
                receiveSum += dataReceivedCounter.NextValue();
            }
            float dataSent = sendSum;
            float dataReceived = receiveSum;


            double dout = (((8 * (dataSent)) / (bandwidth * numberOfIterations) * 100) * 1024) / 100;
            double din = (((8 * (dataReceived)) / (bandwidth * numberOfIterations) * 100) * 1024) / 100;

            dout = Math.Round(dout, 2);
            din = Math.Round(din, 2);

            string doutround = Convert.ToString(dout);
            string dinround = Convert.ToString(din);



            String output = dinround + "/" + doutround;


                GlobalsWMI.NetIOs.Add(output);



        }
        String tooutput = String.Join("AND", GlobalsWMI.NetIOs);
        GlobalsWMI.NetIOs.Clear();
        return tooutput;
```

Comment: How are you running this?  Starting a new process is relatively expensive so if you can start it once and run it periodically that would *probably* reduce the spike.  Also, what kind of numbers are you talking about with instanceNames and numberOfIterations?

Comment: I have ran profiler and can see a couple of things: first PerformanceCounter.NextValue() on my machine uses up 6-10% CPU I don't know why but it just does. Also I noticed that creating the instance names is slow(category.GetInstanceNames()). I wonder is there is a different way to do this.

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer (i'm desperate for rep).

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have tried various things and I think this version is much faster:

```
private string GetNetworkUsage(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] nis)
{

foreach (NetworkInterface ni in nis)
            {
                float bandwidth = ni.Speed;
                const int numberOfIterations = 10;

                float sendSum = 0;
                float receiveSum = 0;

                float lastRec = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
                float lastSent = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent;

                for (int index = 0; index < numberOfIterations; index++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                    float br = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
                    float bs = ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent;
                    receiveSum += br - lastRec;
                    sendSum += bs - lastSent;

                    lastRec = br;
                    lastSent = bs;

                }

                float dataSent = sendSum;
                float dataReceived = receiveSum;

                double dout = (((8 * (dataSent)) / (bandwidth) * 100) * 1024) / 100;
                double din = (((8 * (dataReceived)) / (bandwidth) * 100) * 1024) / 100;

                dout = Math.Round(dout, 2);
                din = Math.Round(din, 2);

                string doutround = Convert.ToString(dout);
                string dinround = Convert.ToString(din);

                String output = dinround + "/" + doutround;


                GlobalsWMI.NetIOs.Add(output);
            }

            String tooutput = String.Join("AND", GlobalsWMI.NetIOs);
            GlobalsWMI.NetIOs.Clear();
            return tooutput;
}
```

call it like this:

```
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] nis = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    // this is you for loop add you sleep or however you do it here
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test(nis));
    }
```

Tried this on my system and it uses less CPU and is faster but I would double check that the figures are as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce CPU usage over the time with a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x) at some points - Your check would last longer but with less average CPU usage.

Comment: No it wouldn't.  It would use the same CPU but over a different period.

Comment: Correct, so the AVERAGE CPU usage is reduced ;-)

Comment: Agreed, but that was not the question.  </pedantry>